# Drawing an E-R Entity using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to define some figures for an E-R diagram. I've already defined the code for relations:

```
\definecolor{RelationColor}{HTML}{E7DBF3}
\tikzset{
    relation/.style = {draw, diamond, text = black, font=\itshape, fill = RelationColor, minimum width = 85pt, minimum height = 65pt, aspect = 1.6},
    weak_relation/.style = {draw, diamond, double, text = black, font=\itshape, fill = RelationColor, minimum width = 85pt, minimum height = 65pt, aspect = 1.6}
}
```

And I'm trying to define now the code for an entity whose style is:

[image: Entity]

But I'm not sure if is possible to draw such figure in Tikz. I was thinking about creating 2 different rectangles, one for the entity title and the second for attributes, but I would not know how to join them together to create such figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with multi-part nodes (requires the `shapes.multipart` library):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, text width=2.5cm, rectangle split part fill={blue!30,none}, font=\itshape, inner sep=5pt] 
    {department
    \nodepart{two} \underline{dept name}\\[3pt]building\\[3pt]budget};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```